# How to get all content by using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to get app info(title and link) from google play by using python scrapy. My network is blocked from visiting google, so I save https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ANDROID_WEAR/collection/topselling_free as a html file to local PC via VPN.

Question1:When use item in parse(), it will show No module named ...item error

Question2:How to get all app info?I only get top 0-60 app info from file.By using web broswer, it have to move to the bottom of the page to show another 60-120 app info and so on. So how to use scrapy to do the same thing?

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "googleplay"
    allowed_domains = ["play.google.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "file://127.0.0.1/C:/Users/abc/Desktop/androidwear.html"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        #filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        print ">>>>>>response:" + str(response)
        #print ">>>>>>response body:" +str(response.body)

        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//div[@class = "details"]/a[@class = "title"]')

        for title in titles:
            title = title.select("text()").extract()
            print title
```

Comment: About the second part of your question: I believe there is some javascript at the bottom of the page which loads the next apps when you scroll down. But scrapy doesn't load nor executes the javascript. Maybe Selenium would be better suited then?

Comment: @vrleboss  I modify code like this, I think it will post data simulate what javascript do:    def start_requests(self):
        return [ FormRequest("https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ANDROID_WEAR/collection/topselling_free",
                     formdata={'start': '0', 'num': '100', 'numChildren': '0', 'ipf': '1', 'xhr': '1'},
                     callback=self.parse) ]